# DNS Zone file and virtual host question

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, centos, redmine

I'm trying to set up a virtual host for redmine.SITENAME.com. I've edited the httpd.conf file and now I'm trying to edit my DNS settings. However, I'm not sure exactly what to do. Here's an snippet of what's already in the named.conf file (the file was made by someone else who is unreachable):

```
zone "SITENAME.com" {
    type master;
    file "SITENAME.com";
    allow-transfer {
            ip.address.here.00;
            common-allow-transfer;
    };
```

};

I figure if I want to get redmine.SITENAME.com working, I need to copy that entry and just replace SITENAME.com with redmine.SITENAME.com but will that work? I was under the impression I needed a .db file but I don't see any reference to one in the current named.conf file. Any advice would be great and if you need more info to answer the question, don't hesitate to ask.